# Conditional based field security

Tags: security

Is there any condition based field security in Drupal? E.g. An administrator can only edit user details users who are from the same Country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement complex field access conditions fairly easily with:

[hook_field_access](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7)